# Повернуть объект с определенной скоростью

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть игровой объект `tower` и триггер `watcher`. При входе в `watcher`игрового объекта `target`, `tower` поворачивается в сторону объекта, который вошел в триггер. 
Сейчас я использую `trasform.lookAt` и все меня устраивает, но вот вопрос, если допустим я хочу добавить `tower` св-во `rotationSpeed`, которое непосредственно влияет на скорость поворота, какой метод или алгоритм мне использовать?

Сейчас код такой:

```
public class Watching : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<GameObject> targets; /* список объектов, которые вошли в триггер */
    public GameObject controledObject; /* tower */

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider target)
    {
        targets.Add(target.gameObject);
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider target)
    {
        targets.Remove(target.gameObject);
    }

    void Update () {
        if(this.targets.Count > 0) {
            GameObject target = this.targets[0];
            controledObject.transform.LookAt(target.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Объясните зачем здесь `this.`, пожалуйста.

Comment: `this` ссылается на текущий экземпляр класса и дает доступ к полю `targets`

Comment: Но ведь так же как и в `OnTriggerEnter(Exit)` область видимости позволяет получить `targets` и без `this.`

Comment: @CGLike, да, тут просто различия в написании стиля (либо this везде, либо уже без него обходиться )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C помощью `LookAt` вряд ли это получится. Можно использовать `Quaternion`

в методе `Update` будет примерно так:

```
void Update () {
    if(this.targets.Count > 0) {
        GameObject target = this.targets[0];

        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - controledObject.transform.position);
        controledObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(controledObject.transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * damping);
    }
}
```

где `damping` это переменная, с помощью которой можно контролировать скорость

Answer (score 0):

Методы для поворота объекта (их много):
`transform.LookAt();`
`transform.Rotate();`
`transform.RotateAround();`
`Quaternion.LookRotation();`
Так же помогут:
`Mathf.Slerp();`